# angular-alert-module build is not working

Tags: angular, ng-build

`"angular-alert-module": "^2.0.3"`

build is not working with this module in `angular 7` version

getting following error

> ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-alert-module/alerts.ngfactory.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'alerts' in
>   'C:\Users\tcd03\Desktop\yalloh\node_modules\angular-alert-module'
>   ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'alerts' in 'C:\Users\tcd03\Desktop\yalloh\src\app'
>   ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ngfactory.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'alerts' in 'C:\Users\tcd03\Desktop\yalloh\src\app'

can any one please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Hey asad ali any idea what might be the issue?